# Login screen showing weird

Tags: release-juno, greeter

[image: New Login Screen]

Well this morning my login screen was showing normal, but after a few hours working on my computer, I suspended and try to login ALL functions are good, just the display is weird, I don't know if some way I installed any dependency that required another GUI that not it's pantheon, so hope that somebody now what I got to do.

Already tried [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/login-screen-incomplete).

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall pantheon-greeter`

But nothing seems to change...

Comment: This is the new greeter - you installed updates in-between: https://blog.elementary.io/say-hello-to-the-new-greeter/

Comment: i have the same update, but i dislike this font image plane, you can switch the full screen background color or image? can u tell me how to can change this in my system. i try with the link of fiddle of the previous answer but i only can change in the online view of the page. Very thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like new Login Screen (LightDM Greeter for Pantheon)

[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/elementary/greeter)

This update was pushed to Juno recently.

You can edit background here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk6u4x29/)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that could be an update, but thank you for the confirmation!